# Migrate from Liferay Portal EE 6.1.20 to Liferay Portal CE 6.1.1

Tags: migration, liferay, liferay-6

I would like to migrate from Liferay Portal EE 6.1.20 GA2 (developed locally with trial version) to Liferay Portal CE 6.1.1 GA2 (client requirement changed).

Is it possible to use the same db (with some downgrade process possibly) and configurations, developed portlets, data etc.? A lot of information is stored in db (organizations hierarchy, users, roles, site and page templates, etc) and it is hard to migrate it manually with exports-imports etc.

Trying to use the same db throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version. Current build version is 6120 and attempting to deploy version 6101.
```

Is it safe to manually change liferay portal's build version in the EE database's release_ table from 6120 to 6101?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, implemented it as described in my question and seems to work fine.

I used the same db as Liferay EE 6.1.20 installation and manually changed liferay portal's build version in the EE database's release_ table from 6120 to 6101.
I used the Liferay CE 6.1.1 bundle with tomcat and I copied from the EE bundle the data folder (with document library files, etc) all my deployed plugins (themes, portlets, hooks etc) in webapps folder, all configuration files (portal-ext.properties, etc.).

I now only throws in the logs an exception about the marketplace plugin version but it seems unobtrusive and invisible to the user and event the marketplace feature works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the connection to database written in context.xml inside tomcat/conf folder. 
Make sure you check the connection and it is pointing to the right database. and also deleting all the rows in release_ table helped me.