# Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, liferay, hsqldb

I have a really weird issue to solve. I'm getting following error line when trying to start **Liferay Portal**  on **Tomcat**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version. Current build version is 6201 and attempting to deploy version 6101.
at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:105)
at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:144)
at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1306)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:214)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've found only topics where people actually wanted to upgrade portal and got this message. What my workspace looks like is as this:

- Windows, localhost,
- Liferay 6.1 CE bundled with Tomcat, running on JRE 6, using PostgreSQL,
- Liferay 6.2 CE bundled with Tomcat, running on JRE 7, using HSQL.

I don't want to upgrade, I just want to have both versions present.

Thanks guys!

Comment: look if following link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967379/migrate-from-liferay-portal-ee-6-1-20-to-liferay-portal-ce-6-1-1

Comment: Sorry, I haven't expressed myself clearly, I want to use both versions (no, not at the same time), not migrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Liferay installation directory you'll typically find a file named portal-ext.properties. This typically has the configuration for the database that Liferay shall use. Both versions that you are running should point to a different database, then you can have both installations in paralell.

If you want to run them at the same time, you'll also need to modify tomcat (assuming that's the appserver you use. Look for all `port="xxxx"` declarations in `tomcat/conf/server.xml` and change them to distinct values (OOTB there are three for every tomcat installation). In Eclipse/Liferay IDE you can also find the port declaration in the server information screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link as it helps me.
[Click here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/18188268)

There is a table called release_ which contains a column build number. 
This has build number.
I faced same issue so I deleted only this table and then restart server again.
I have back up for my db for version liferay 6.2 cega2.
I tried to install same version in different machine and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error comes when you point Liferay of version X(6.2.0.1)  with database of Liferay version Y(6.1.0.1).

You first have to migrate your database.

Refer link for [6.2 migration](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/upgrading-liferay-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-18-en)

EDIT====

You can have different database schema for different Liferay version. You can not run different version with same database schema.

Comment: OK, I want to have both versions on the disk and work with one I need at the moment. How should I solve this? I thought that I'm working with two different databases.

Comment: you can have different database for different Liferay version. You can not run different version with same database schema.

Comment: I understand, I don't want that. It is possible that I somehow connected with 6.2 to the former database. Is it somehow possible to downgrade the db now?

Comment: I did not get your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to put it simple: can I downgrade Liferay 6.2 compatible database to 6.1?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can only restore db from backup.